# name error in multiprocess pool IMapIterator.next(self, timeout)

Tags: python, pool, multiprocess

in the following code, after defining run_experiment and run_wrapper using multiprocess pool.imap raised Name Error in execution. Also I added freez_support() but still get NameError: name 'run_experiment' is not defined! even though I define the run_experiment. could you please help to solve the problem?

```py
    def run_experiment(args, order):
    # Make a data containers
    QbData = QubitExperiment()
    
    # Resample the control
    resampled_args = hf.resample_u_dft(args, n_discretization)
    control = hf.u_idft(ts, resampled_args)
    
    # Run the experiment
    psi0 = qt.basis(2,1)
    H = [H0, [H1, control]]
    result = qt.mesolve(H, psi0, ts, [], measure_list)
    X = np.array(result.expect)
            
    # Collect strobe data
    Y = fshape(X[:,::i_strobe],  n_strobes)
    Ty = ts[::i_period]

    # We only have monotone controls so we just repeat the pulse
    control_library = [hf.make_control_library(args['u_hat'], order)]*n_periods
    Uy = np.hstack(control_library)
    
    # Save data
    QbData.save(X, Y, Uy, Ty, resampled_args)
    
    return QbData

    # Library order
    order = 3

    # Run multi-thread experiments
    def run_wrapper(arg):
        return run_experiment(arg, order=order)
    # protect the entry point
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    # add freeze support for multiprocessing
        mp.freeze_support()
        with pool.Pool(2) as p:
            r = list(p.imap(run_wrapper, control_list))
        QbData = join_qubit_experiments(r)
```

you can see the traceback of execution:

```
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IIGII\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "", line 33, in run_wrapper
NameError: name 'run_experiment' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 39
     37 mp.freeze_support()
     38 with pool.Pool(2) as p:
---> 39     r = list(p.imap(run_wrapper, control_list))
     40 QbData = join_qubit_experiments(r)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py:873, in IMapIterator.next(self, timeout)
    871 if success:
    872     return value
--> 873 raise value
NameError: name 'run_experiment' is not defined
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm the author of `multiprocess`. From your code above, `run_experiment` is not defined, so you are getting a `NameError`.  You should import `run_experiment` inside `run_wrappper` so it is defined when it's sent to the child process.  It also seems you are on Windows, so you will probably want to add `freeze_support` in `__main__`.

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation?  If that code were indented correctly, it should work.